# char* array initialization

Tags: c, char, segmentation-fault

I have this array:

```
char *tags[100];
```

If I do this:

```
tags[0]="something";
```

It works (no errors at least). However, the very same code in a for loop doesn't.

```
int j=0;       
for(j; j<100; ++j)
{
    tags[j]="something";
}
```

It says "Segmentation fault". What is this?

UPDATE: Whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void append(char* s, char c)
{
        int len = strlen(s);
        s[len] = c;
        s[len+1] = '\0';
}


int main()
{
   int istag;
   FILE *fopen(), *fp;
   int i;
   fp = fopen("oldal.html","r");
   i= getc(fp) ;
   char* szo;

   int index=0;
   char *tags[100]; 

int j=0;       
for(j; j<100; ++j)
{
    tags[j]="something";
}


   while (i!= EOF)
   {            

        i = getc(fp);
        char c=i;

        if(c=='<')
        {
            istag=1;
        }
        if(c=='>')
        {
            istag=0;
            index++;
            //printf("tag vege: %s %d",tags[index],index);


        }

        if(istag)
        {

            //append(tags[index],'a');
        }

        append(szo,c);


   }

   //printf("%s",szo);
   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @elyashiv Still doesn't explain why the error. And no, allocating new strings is not the same as just making them point to constant string literals (no matter what is better here, it isn't related to the actual question).

Comment: try to see how much memory has been allocated from your code and how much data you are writing in either method

Comment: @NicholeGrace No, don't do that. At least the question doesn't suggest in anyway that the code is meant to do this.

Comment: I can't see how this segfaults. At least not in this code. There must be either additional code or the code, which segfaults, looks different.

Comment: oh I read the question wrong , this makes sense ,thanks christian

Comment: I do not like the lonely `j` in the arguments to `for()`.

Comment: @alk the lonely `j` is just a noop.

Comment: Tried.  Works fine for me.  Please post complete code sample with compiler.

Comment: @alk In fact I don't even like the declaration of `j` outside the loop, but alas it's C unfortunately ;) But you're right in that it looks a bit misplaced, still no error, though.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the code to possibly suggest a segfault. Perhaps, you do something else in other parts of the code that's giving segfault. Can you post a complete snippet that you compile & run?

Comment: `s[len] = c;` boom, boom out go the lights ... ;-)

Comment: Note that, as written, each element of `tags` is initially pointing to a *string literal*; if you try to call `append` on an element of `tags`, you'll be invoking undefined behavior by attempting to modify the contents of a string literal.  Right now you have that call commented out, so it isn't your problem, but it will be a problem if you put it back in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code calls your append() function to append data to `szo`, but `szo` was never initialized and contains whatever value happened to be on the stack where it is declared.

Who knows where it is writing to. This is almost certainly the cause of the problem.

Initialize `szo` by pointing it to a character buffer of sufficient size. Remember to make it big enough to hold even the data and terminators that are appended.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand how the code seemed right when I didn't use that for loop.

Comment: Errors like this are very random depending on whatever the value of that pointer's memory was. So the type of error that results can be very unpredictable, or even appear not to have any error.

Answer (score 3):

It means there is an error elsewhere in your code.  There is no error in the code you posted, end of discussion.

Update:  *sigh*

```
        s[len+1] = '\0';
```

is wrong.

Please run your code in a debugger to see the line the error originates on in the future - as it wasn't even a line in the code you posted.

Comment: Finally the only correct answer. Though, it's still arguable if this should rather be a comment than an answer, even if it is pretty welcome in the end.

Comment: Any assignment to the uninitialized memory referenced by `s` is UB.

Comment: This is not a discussion site, it is a question and answer site.  Phrases such as *end of discussion* and *sigh* don't belong in an answer.  Also, `s[len+1] = '\0';` is fine as `len` isn't recalculated after appending `c`.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with the line `s[len+1] = '\0';`. In fact, this is related to the issue because `s` was never initialized. But in that case, it's really the line `s[len] = c;` where the problem first occurs. Were `s` to refer to a sufficiently sized buffer, this code would be perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3):

The segmentation fault most likely comes from the line `append(szo,c);`, as `szo` at that point is an unitialized pointer, and you are passing it into a function that attempts to use the pointer to derive a memory location to write into.

Answer (score 1):

it should be s[len] = '\0' instead of s[len+1] = '\0';. ALso as the other user said, szo is never initialized. It points to a random location which may/maynot be an accessible location. Causing the segmentation violation

Comment: I still wonder why I was downvoted @alk

Comment: my answer is similar to his :-/

Comment: This is wrong. `s[len]` is assigned the character and so the new terminator would indeed be at `s[len+1]`. The problem is related to initialization of `szo`, otherwise the `append()` function is perfectly valid.

Comment: strlen() returns number of characters in the string. For example, if there are 32(s[0]->s[31]) characters in the string, s[32] should be '\0' character and not s[33]. djchelin also got confused with one of the versions posted.

Comment: @PrototypeStart: No, you are wrong. The `append()` function is appending to an existing string. So `s[32]` gets the appended character (which replaces the old terminator), and `s[32+1]` gets the new '\0' terminator. That part of the code is correct. If you set `s[32] = '\0'` then you would overwrite the character you just appended.